# UIImage to cv::Mat CV_8UC3

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv, uiimage

There are a ton of questions about converting a UIIMage to a cv::Mat with CV_8UC4 encoding. There's even the [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html) on the OpenCV iOS site.

However, for the life of me I can't figure out how to convert a UIImage to 8UC3 correctly. Using the stock OpenCV example, trying to convert to 8UC1 also breaks, as the cv:Mat has a ton of null pointers after initialization.

Any insight into how I might be able to do this correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me when I want to convert from UIImage into Mat simply I use the predefined function
UIImageToMat like this:

```
UIImageToMat(extractedUIImage, matImage);
```

But first you need to include this header file from openCV:

```
#import <opencv2/highgui/ios.h>
```

Same to convert from Mat into UIImage:

```
UIImage *extractedImage = MatToUIImage(matImage);
```

Just give it a try it works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Try calling the following after converting UIImage to cv::Mat...

cvtColor(srcMat, destMat, CV_RGBA2BGR);